# How to achieve "radio" by "button"

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, radio-button

I want to have a Radio features(M or F).

But I can't use its. (It can't achieve the style what I want)

```
<input type="radio" id="Member_Sex_boy" class="btn btn-default" onclick="ChangeColor_boy();" name="Member_Sex" VALUE="1" CHECKED >MAN</input>
```

The picture is that use `<input type="radio"...`

https://goo.gl/RCaMgP

But I want like the picture. (use `<button type="radio"...` or `<label type="radio"...`)

https://goo.gl/37FzCF

But, if it is `<button type="radio"...`: When I press the radio, it submits automatically the form.

And, if it is `<label type="radio"...`: When I press the submit button,it can't sent data for database.

So I want to achieve `radio` with `button`.

(EX. `<button type="button"...` and it can radio item)

(Sorry, I can't post picture.)

Comment: You will have to use a library like Bootstrap, or custom code your own buttons that are either tied to radio buttons, or simply act like them. Native radio buttons do not look like that.

Comment: You might want to look at something like: https://jqueryui.com/button/#radio

Comment: I use Bootstrap to write the program(class="btn btn-default")~
But I want to know how to use javascript to achieve radio by button~

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using only css, just takes a bit of creativity ;)

```css
input[name='sex'] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
input[name='sex']:after {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  content: attr(value);
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 40px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
input[name='sex']:checked:after {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="f" checked />
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="m" />
```

Comment: If for some reason the OP can't use pseudo classes, here's the javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/snlacks/6m0s8x51/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not taking the time to write the code here, but hopefully this will guide you on what you need to look for.

You can prevent the submitting of form that is happening on click of the button by preventing the click event propagation.

For the buttons to act as radio buttons, keep a hidden form field whose value you can update to M or F based on what button is clicked. When the form is submitted, this value will automatically be sent along with the other form data.

On load of the form again, check the value of this hidden field, and accordingly update the display of the buttons using css.

In short, this would be a way to replicate what the html form element  does using different UI elements and javascript.

This is the longer route. A shorter route would be to use some kind of UI library that overlays the underlying form elements to give enhanced look. Check out jquery mobile as one example.